# firefox extension multiple windows callback function error

Tags: firefox, callback

I am working on firefox extension with multiple windows. I am using Example 2 on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code.

I have a sidebar which call a popup window. Sidebar is parent and popup window is child.

I can share variables from parent window to child window. It calls callback function (which is in parent window) correctly. However, if callback function has to call some other function from parent window. It does not work.

Is it a scope issue? Why callback function is not able to call other functions in parent window?

What is a right way of doing this.

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Without more information (like the error message from Error Console), I would suspect that it is a permissions issue. Your pop-up window probably doesn't have the permissions to access chrome code (e.g. if about:blank, data: or a file:// URL is loaded into it rather than chrome://). So the parent window is allowed to call functions in the child window but not the other way round.